# Java Generics child backreference to parent / selecting on subclass properties

Tags: java, generics, hql

I have a generic class that can be extended and generic child members that can be extended. 
I'm trying to to make the group reference in SpecialGroupMember be SpecialGroup in stead of "Group", mainly because in Hibernate HQL I want to select SpecialGroupMembers based on the special property of SpecialGroup.  In the configuration below, Hibernate will throw an error on the following query

```
from SpecialGroupMember sgm inner join sgm.group grp where grp.special = true;



public class Group<T extends GroupMember>{
    private List<T> members;
}

public class SpecialGroup extends Group<SpecialMember>{
    private boolean special;
}

public class GroupMember{

    private Group<? extends GroupMember> group;
}

public class SpecialGroupMember extends GroupMember{
    private boolean something;
}
```

Any suggestions how to set this up in a meaningful way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special property needs to be present in Group to (maybe set to false) to be able to select via Group. As the property in GroupMember is a Group and not a SpecialGroup only properties of the Group class are accessible.

```
public class Group<T extends GroupMember>{
    protected boolean special = false;
    private List<T> members;
}

public class SpecialGroup extends Group<SpecialMember>{
     public SpecialGroup() {
         special = true;
}

public class GroupMember{

    private Group<? extends GroupMember> group;
}

public class SpecialGroupMember extends GroupMember{
    private boolean something;
}
```

While one of the main use cases of Hibernate or any other ORM-framework is to provide things like inheritance to database-objects, in my opinion it's not very good at this. Trying to use this feature for more than described in the docs will in most cases result in a nightmare.